# Python print issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using below code (simplified for this question):

```
t1=['1.99','2','133.37']
t2=['4.98','5','11116.98']
t3=list(zip(t1,t2))
t4=[]
for num1,num2 in t3:
  t4.append(float(num1)+float(num2))
print('The sum is='+ ":".join(map(str,t4)))
# output is -> The sum is=6.970000000000001:7.0:11250.35
```

But I want the output to be as below:

```
The sum is=6.970000:7.000000:11250.350000
# i.e. six digits ONLY after decimal point
```

How do I do that?

Comment: +1 as I can see no reason why someone downvoted the beginners question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `format`:

```
>>> format(5.2, '.6f')
'5.200000'
```

The `.6` means “to six decimal places” and the `f` means a floating point number.

To put this into your existing code, use a `lambda` as the argument to `map` rather than `str`:

```
print('The sum is=' + ":".join(map(lambda n: format(n, '.6f'), t4)))
```

You could also replace your `map` call with a generator expression:

```
print('The sum is=' + ":".join(format(n, '.6f') for n in t4))
```

Comment: Probably better to use a genex instead of `map()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
print('The sum is={:.6f}:{:.6f}:{:.6f}'.format(*t4))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t4.append("%.6f" % (float(num1)+float(num2)))
```

`"%.6f" % anumber` means convert anumber to a `f`loating point number, then format with `6` digits after the `.`

Answer (score 0):

formatting can be done with %.6f for up to 6 decimal places

```
t1=['1.99','2','133.37']
t2=['4.98','5','11116.98']
t3=list(zip(t1,t2))
t4=[]
print('The sum is='+ ":"),
for num1,num2 in t3:
    each_sum = float(num1)+float(num2)
    print(":%.6f"%each_sum),
```